# How to extract lines with common fields

Tags: bash, sed, awk, uniq

I have a file like this -

```
1 2 3
1 4 5
a z 3
a 3 4
a f g
b b g
```

I want to split it into multiple files (as many as there are groups) each containing those lines that have the same first field.

```
 1 2 3
 1 4 5

 a z 3
 a 3 4
 a f g

 b b g
```

How do I do that? I tried `uniq --all-repeated=separate -w 32` but it considers complete line and not just first column when finding duplicates.

Comment: Won't `sort` group them for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$ awk '{print > $1}' input

$ cat 1
1 2 3
1 4 5

$ cat a
a z 3
a 3 4
a f g

$ cat b
b b g
```

Comment: You want `>` not `>>` awks redirection operator are not the same as the shells.

Comment: True, filehandle is open for the duration of the script. Updated

Comment: `$1` is the first field on a line, `$2` the second and so on. `print`, well, prints the whole line which is directed to a file which is named after the first field. The filehandle is open for the duration of the script, hence lines will be appended to it.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly nicer file naming approach:

```
$ ls
file

$ awk '!($1 in a){a[$1]="file"++i}{print > a[$1]}' file

$ ls
file  file1  file2  file3

$ cat file1
1 2 3
1 4 5

$ cat file2
a z 3
a 3 4
a f g

$ cat file3
b b g
```